# Laravel request int and string keys weird behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Imagine - Laravel application, a get requst is made.

The situation is, that a custom request, which has inputs with integer names, is made. In the custom request file I'm adding another field, lets say "fields". So at first the `$request->all()` returns

```
array(
     1 => "value1",
     5 => "value5",
     12 => "value12",
)
```

and after adding the new field `$request->all()` returns

```
array(
     1 => "value1",
     5 => "value5",
     12 => "value12",
     "fields" => array(
                      "key" => "value",
                 ),
)
```

Now the problem occurs - `$request->get("fields")` returns null.

`$request->all()` returns with fields.

`$request->only(["fields"])` returns array with fields.

`$request->exists("fields")` returns true.

Why is it so?

---

**EDIT**

Adding the new field inside the custom request class:

```
public function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    $validator->after(function() use ($validator, $event)
    {
         $this->merge(["fields" => ["key" => "value"]]);
    }
    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: How you are adding?

Comment: I've never used $request->get() before, can you try your code with $request->input('fields') instead?

Comment: Show us your code where you add fields

Comment: @itachi updated question

Comment: @IzumiYanaro it works indeed. Thank you!. I've got a big project and I've only used ...->get(). I'm wondering why doesn't it work at this moment

Comment: @MihkelAllorg You're probably confused with input->get(), there's no request->get(), only request->input();

Comment: There is get() in a parent class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

Answer (score 1):

`$request->all()` should return all data submitted through the request. Behaving as it should.

`$request->only(["fields"])` is getting the `fields` key from the request and casting it to an array due to the `[]`. Normal behavior

`$request->exists("fields")` is just checking if that key exists in the request data. Normal behavior

Looking into `Illuminate\Http\Request`, I do not see a `get()` method. I only method I have seen used to extract input from a request is `$request->input('fieldName')`. However there is a `__get()` method in `Illuminate\Http\Request` that seems to work. I would stick with the `input()` method since it is more explicit.

Comment: `Request::get` is defined in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, the parent class.

Comment: Ah, didn't dig far enough down :P . Thx

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AndrewNolan, but my question was why isn't the get() method working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you may have a simple scoping issue, and `$this` isn't available in your validator's `after` closure:

```
$validator->after(function() use ($validator, $event, $this)
{
     $this->merge(["fields" => ["key" => "value"]]);
}
```

If you're using [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) or below the above won't work, you will need to capture a reference to `$this` in the parent scope:

```
$self = $this;
$validator->after(function() use ($validator, $event, $self)
{
     $self->merge(["fields" => ["key" => "value"]]);
}
```

Comment: If I had a scoping issue, ..->exists("fields") would return false, and in ...->all() it wouldn't show either. good guess tho